# got Fixnum: Rails rollback error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

hello i'm doing a migration on ruby on rails:

```
 class CombineItemsInCart < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def up
        Cart.all.each do |cart|
            sums = cart.line_items.group(:product_id).sum(:quantity)

            sums.each do |product_id, quantity|
                cart.line_items.where(product_id: product_id).delete_all

                item = cart.line_items.build(product_id: product_id)
                item.quantity = quantity
                item.save!
            end
        end
    end

    def down
        LineItem.where("quantity>1").each do |line_item|
            line_item.quantity.times do 
                LineItem.create cart_id: line_item.cart_id,
                product: line_item.product_id, quantity: 1
            end
            line_item.destroy
        end
    end

end
```

when i type in my console the rollback comand i recive this error:

```
Product(#58221600) expected, got Fixnum(#17692120)/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:218:in `raise_on_type_mismatch!
```

why it say that i'm assign a fixnum?
thanks for all the help

Comment: In the `def down` this line `product: line_item.product_id` should be `product_id: line_item.product_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `product: line_item.product_id` should be product: `line_item.product`

```
def down
    LineItem.where("quantity>1").each do |line_item|
        line_item.quantity.times do 
            LineItem.create cart_id: line_item.cart_id,
            product: line_item.product, quantity: 1
        end
        line_item.destroy
    end
end
```

OR you can also do it like this :

```
def down
    LineItem.where("quantity>1").each do |line_item|
        line_item.quantity.times do 
            LineItem.create cart_id: line_item.cart_id,
            product_id: line_item.product_id, quantity: 1
        end
        line_item.destroy
    end
end
```

Comment: gooood, i was so stupid that i haven't noticed before thanks a lot